# mysql query and cookies

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**newbies should be encouraged. rather discouraging**

I am new an having problems in understanding docs of php.

can someone give the exact code steps for my future reference to :

I want to run this query:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT tracking_code FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE     language_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "'");
```

(I know it will return only one value) and 1. if "if tacking named cookie exists, delete it or replace it and set a cookie named "tracking" for one year with the value returned by that query. How can i do it?

I know little about php  . but i get the feeling that i have no reference to db in that confirm.php  . it doesnot extends model, nor i know would $this work here or not
the file iam working on is.

```
<?php 
class ControllerCheckoutConfirm extends Controller { 
    public function index() {
        $redirect = '';

        if ($this->cart->hasShipping()) {
            // Validate if shipping address has been set.       
            $this->load->model('account/address');

            if ($this->customer->isLogged() && isset($this->session->data['shipping_address_id'])) {                    
                $shipping_address = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->session->data['shipping_address_id']);      
            } elseif (isset($this->session->data['guest'])) {
                $shipping_address = $this->session->data['guest']['shipping'];
            }

            if (empty($shipping_address)) {                             
                $redirect = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', 'SSL');
            }

            // Validate if shipping method has been set.    
            if (!isset($this->session->data['shipping_method'])) {
                $redirect = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', 'SSL');
            }
        } else {
            unset($this->session->data['shipping_method']);
            unset($this->session->data['shipping_methods']);
        }

        // Validate if payment address has been set.
        $this->load->model('account/address');

        if ($this->customer->isLogged() && isset($this->session->data['payment_address_id'])) {
            $payment_address = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->session->data['payment_address_id']);        
        } elseif (isset($this->session->data['guest'])) {
            $payment_address = $this->session->data['guest']['payment'];
        }   

        if (empty($payment_address)) {
            $redirect = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', 'SSL');
        }           

        // Validate if payment method has been set. 
        if (!isset($this->session->data['payment_method'])) {
            $redirect = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', 'SSL');
        }

        // Validate cart has products and has stock.    
        if ((!$this->cart->hasProducts() && empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) || (!$this->cart->hasStock() && !$this->config->get('config_stock_checkout'))) {
            $redirect = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');              
        }   

        // Validate minimum quantity requirments.           
        $products = $this->cart->getProducts();

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $product_total = 0;

            foreach ($products as $product_2) {
                if ($product_2['product_id'] == $product['product_id']) {
                    $product_total += $product_2['quantity'];
                }
            }       

            if ($product['minimum'] > $product_total) {
                $redirect = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');

                break;
            }               
        }

        if (!$redirect) {
            $total_data = array();
            $total = 0;
            $taxes = $this->cart->getTaxes();

            $this->load->model('setting/extension');

            $sort_order = array(); 

            $results = $this->model_setting_extension->getExtensions('total');

            foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
                $sort_order[$key] = $this->config->get($value['code'] . '_sort_order');
            }

            array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $results);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                if ($this->config->get($result['code'] . '_status')) {
                    $this->load->model('total/' . $result['code']);

                    $this->{'model_total_' . $result['code']}->getTotal($total_data, $total, $taxes);
                }
            }

            $sort_order = array(); 

            foreach ($total_data as $key => $value) {
                $sort_order[$key] = $value['sort_order'];
            }

            array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $total_data);

            $this->language->load('checkout/checkout');

            $data = array();

            $data['invoice_prefix'] = $this->config->get('config_invoice_prefix');
            $data['store_id'] = $this->config->get('config_store_id');
            $data['store_name'] = $this->config->get('config_name');

            if ($data['store_id']) {
                $data['store_url'] = $this->config->get('config_url');      
            } else {
                $data['store_url'] = HTTP_SERVER;   
            }

            if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
                $data['customer_id'] = $this->customer->getId();
                $data['customer_group_id'] = $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId();
                $data['firstname'] = $this->customer->getFirstName();
                $data['lastname'] = $this->customer->getLastName();
                $data['email'] = $this->customer->getEmail();
                $data['telephone'] = $this->customer->getTelephone();
                $data['fax'] = $this->customer->getFax();

                $this->load->model('account/address');

                $payment_address = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->session->data['payment_address_id']);
            } elseif (isset($this->session->data['guest'])) {
                $data['customer_id'] = 0;
                $data['customer_group_id'] = $this->session->data['guest']['customer_group_id'];
                $data['firstname'] = $this->session->data['guest']['firstname'];
                $data['lastname'] = $this->session->data['guest']['lastname'];
                $data['email'] = $this->session->data['guest']['email'];
                $data['telephone'] = $this->session->data['guest']['telephone'];
                $data['fax'] = $this->session->data['guest']['fax'];

                $payment_address = $this->session->data['guest']['payment'];
            }

            $data['payment_firstname'] = $payment_address['firstname'];
            $data['payment_lastname'] = $payment_address['lastname'];   
            $data['payment_company'] = $payment_address['company']; 
            $data['payment_company_id'] = $payment_address['company_id'];   
            $data['payment_tax_id'] = $payment_address['tax_id'];   
            $data['payment_address_1'] = $payment_address['address_1'];
            $data['payment_address_2'] = $payment_address['address_2'];
            $data['payment_city'] = $payment_address['city'];
            $data['payment_postcode'] = $payment_address['postcode'];
            $data['payment_zone'] = $payment_address['zone'];
            $data['payment_zone_id'] = $payment_address['zone_id'];
            $data['payment_country'] = $payment_address['country'];
            $data['payment_country_id'] = $payment_address['country_id'];
            $data['payment_address_format'] = $payment_address['address_format'];

            if (isset($this->session->data['payment_method']['title'])) {
                $data['payment_method'] = $this->session->data['payment_method']['title'];
            } else {
                $data['payment_method'] = '';
            }

            if (isset($this->session->data['payment_method']['code'])) {
                $data['payment_code'] = $this->session->data['payment_method']['code'];
            } else {
                $data['payment_code'] = '';
            }

            if ($this->cart->hasShipping()) {
                if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
                    $this->load->model('account/address');

                    $shipping_address = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($this->session->data['shipping_address_id']);  
                } elseif (isset($this->session->data['guest'])) {
                    $shipping_address = $this->session->data['guest']['shipping'];
                }           

                $data['shipping_firstname'] = $shipping_address['firstname'];
                $data['shipping_lastname'] = $shipping_address['lastname']; 
                $data['shipping_company'] = $shipping_address['company'];   
                $data['shipping_address_1'] = $shipping_address['address_1'];
                $data['shipping_address_2'] = $shipping_address['address_2'];
                $data['shipping_city'] = $shipping_address['city'];
                $data['shipping_postcode'] = $shipping_address['postcode'];
                $data['shipping_zone'] = $shipping_address['zone'];
                $data['shipping_zone_id'] = $shipping_address['zone_id'];
                $data['shipping_country'] = $shipping_address['country'];
                $data['shipping_country_id'] = $shipping_address['country_id'];
                $data['shipping_address_format'] = $shipping_address['address_format'];

                if (isset($this->session->data['shipping_method']['title'])) {
                    $data['shipping_method'] = $this->session->data['shipping_method']['title'];
                } else {
                    $data['shipping_method'] = '';
                }

                if (isset($this->session->data['shipping_method']['code'])) {
                    $data['shipping_code'] = $this->session->data['shipping_method']['code'];
                } else {
                    $data['shipping_code'] = '';
                }               
            } else {
                $data['shipping_firstname'] = '';
                $data['shipping_lastname'] = '';    
                $data['shipping_company'] = ''; 
                $data['shipping_address_1'] = '';
                $data['shipping_address_2'] = '';
                $data['shipping_city'] = '';
                $data['shipping_postcode'] = '';
                $data['shipping_zone'] = '';
                $data['shipping_zone_id'] = '';
                $data['shipping_country'] = '';
                $data['shipping_country_id'] = '';
                $data['shipping_address_format'] = '';
                $data['shipping_method'] = '';
                $data['shipping_code'] = '';
            }

            $product_data = array();

            foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {
                $option_data = array();

                foreach ($product['option'] as $option) {
                    if ($option['type'] != 'file') {
                        $value = $option['option_value'];   
                    } else {
                        $value = $this->encryption->decrypt($option['option_value']);
                    }   

                    $option_data[] = array(
                        'product_option_id'       => $option['product_option_id'],
                        'product_option_value_id' => $option['product_option_value_id'],
                        'option_id'               => $option['option_id'],
                        'option_value_id'         => $option['option_value_id'],                                   
                        'name'                    => $option['name'],
                        'value'                   => $value,
                        'type'                    => $option['type']
                    );                  
                }

                $product_data[] = array(
                    'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
                    'name'       => $product['name'],
                    'model'      => $product['model'],
                    'option'     => $option_data,
                    'download'   => $product['download'],
                    'quantity'   => $product['quantity'],
                    'subtract'   => $product['subtract'],
                    'price'      => $product['price'],
                    'total'      => $product['total'],
                    'tax'        => $this->tax->getTax($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id']),
                    'reward'     => $product['reward']
                ); 
            }

            // Gift Voucher
            $voucher_data = array();

            if (!empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) {
                foreach ($this->session->data['vouchers'] as $voucher) {
                    $voucher_data[] = array(
                        'description'      => $voucher['description'],
                        'code'             => substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 10),
                        'to_name'          => $voucher['to_name'],
                        'to_email'         => $voucher['to_email'],
                        'from_name'        => $voucher['from_name'],
                        'from_email'       => $voucher['from_email'],
                        'voucher_theme_id' => $voucher['voucher_theme_id'],
                        'message'          => $voucher['message'],                      
                        'amount'           => $voucher['amount']
                    );
                }
            }  

            $data['products'] = $product_data;
            $data['vouchers'] = $voucher_data;
            $data['totals'] = $total_data;
            $data['comment'] = $this->session->data['comment'];
            $data['total'] = $total;




            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT affiliate_code FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE language_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "'");

            //set cookie $query->rows;






            if (isset($this->request->cookie['tracking'])) {
                $this->load->model('affiliate/affiliate');

                $affiliate_info = $this->model_affiliate_affiliate->getAffiliateByCode($this->request->cookie['tracking']);
                $subtotal = $this->cart->getSubTotal();

                if ($affiliate_info) {
                    $data['affiliate_id'] = $affiliate_info['affiliate_id']; 
                    $data['commission'] = ($subtotal / 100) * $affiliate_info['commission']; 
                } else {
                    $data['affiliate_id'] = 0;
                    $data['commission'] = 0;
                }
            } else {
                $data['affiliate_id'] = 0;
                $data['commission'] = 0;
            }

            $data['language_id'] = $this->config->get('config_language_id');
            $data['currency_id'] = $this->currency->getId();
            $data['currency_code'] = $this->currency->getCode();
            $data['currency_value'] = $this->currency->getValue($this->currency->getCode());
            $data['ip'] = $this->request->server['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            if (!empty($this->request->server['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
                $data['forwarded_ip'] = $this->request->server['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']; 
            } elseif(!empty($this->request->server['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
                $data['forwarded_ip'] = $this->request->server['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];   
            } else {
                $data['forwarded_ip'] = '';
            }

            if (isset($this->request->server['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
                $data['user_agent'] = $this->request->server['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];    
            } else {
                $data['user_agent'] = '';
            }

            if (isset($this->request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
                $data['accept_language'] = $this->request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];  
            } else {
                $data['accept_language'] = '';
            }

            $this->load->model('checkout/order');

            $this->session->data['order_id'] = $this->model_checkout_order->addOrder($data);

            $this->data['column_name'] = $this->language->get('column_name');
            $this->data['column_model'] = $this->language->get('column_model');
            $this->data['column_quantity'] = $this->language->get('column_quantity');
            $this->data['column_price'] = $this->language->get('column_price');
            $this->data['column_total'] = $this->language->get('column_total');

            $this->data['products'] = array();

            foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {
                $option_data = array();

                foreach ($product['option'] as $option) {
                    if ($option['type'] != 'file') {
                        $value = $option['option_value'];   
                    } else {
                        $filename = $this->encryption->decrypt($option['option_value']);

                        $value = utf8_substr($filename, 0, utf8_strrpos($filename, '.'));
                    }

                    $option_data[] = array(
                        'name'  => $option['name'],
                        'value' => (utf8_strlen($value) > 20 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 20) . '..' : $value)
                    );
                }  

                $this->data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
                    'name'       => $product['name'],
                    'model'      => $product['model'],
                    'option'     => $option_data,
                    'quantity'   => $product['quantity'],
                    'subtract'   => $product['subtract'],
                    'price'      => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax'))),
                    'total'      => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')) * $product['quantity']),
                    'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id'])
                ); 
            } 

            // Gift Voucher
            $this->data['vouchers'] = array();

            if (!empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) {
                foreach ($this->session->data['vouchers'] as $voucher) {
                    $this->data['vouchers'][] = array(
                        'description' => $voucher['description'],
                        'amount'      => $this->currency->format($voucher['amount'])
                    );
                }
            }  

            $this->data['totals'] = $total_data;

            $this->data['payment'] = $this->getChild('payment/' . $this->session->data['payment_method']['code']);
        } else {
            $this->data['redirect'] = $redirect;
        }           

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/checkout/confirm.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/checkout/confirm.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/checkout/confirm.tpl';
        }

        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());    
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where did you get all this? What is $db (or $this), what tracking are you talking about, etc.

Comment: Your question isnt very clear, makes it hard for us to help.

Comment: its in opencart and mysql.  catalog/controler/checkout/confirm.php  the file code is in the update

Comment: Adding more than 400 lines of code is not going to help either...

Comment: is it if ($query->row) { setcookie("tracking", $query->row['tracking_code'], time()+32850000); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done this way .

```
<?php
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT tracking_code FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE     language_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "'");

   if(isset($_COOKIE['tracking'])){
      setcookie('tracking', '', time()-1);
      sleep(1); // sleep for 1 sec
      setcookie('tracking', '$query->row["tracking_code"]', time()+60*60*24*30*12);
   }else{
      setcookie('tracking', '$query->row["tracking_code"]', time()+60*60*24*30*12);
   }
?>
```

So in the if condition ,if your cookie named tracking is set than it will delete it with 1 sec and and apply you new value from $query . I hope this will work .

Comment: it my question was a little valid. eliminate the -1s for the new bie gift the people just gave.  what happens if tracking cookies is already made, and i try to remake it. will the value and time be overwriiten?
<Quest> thanks any ways.. and thanks!

Comment: @Masood :  Sorry i may be unable to understand properly what you have wriiten in the comment . But yes your question is valid and make sense .

Comment: Yes according to my code . if the tracking cookie already exits . then using set cookie on it with time of less then a second . It will be destroyed . And then again a cookie will be set with your new query value .

Comment: Thanks A lot. accepted with +1 and thanks of pleasure. newbies should be encouraged. rather discouraging

Comment: shouldnt it be $query->row['affiliate_code'] instead of  $query["tracking_code"]'  in setcookie('tracking', '$query["tracking_code"]', time()+60*60*24*30*12);

Comment: but in the query you are selecting tracking_code . check your query .

Comment: sorry, tracking_code and affiliate_code is same. what about  the query syntax?

Comment: should it be $query->row['tracking_code'] instead of $query["tracking_code"]'    ?